# How to concat data from database and send it to a string using asp.net/c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arduino, sql-server-2014

I need to concatenate some data from my database and send it to a string. My string, in turn, will send it to a code on arduino and it will light up some LEDs according to the `[Line]`, `[Location]` and `[Qtd]`. My database consists of:

```
[TrackCode]     [Pn]     [Location]     [Line]      [Qtd]
---------------------------------------------------------
[GP6JLG2]     [JNKWD]   [HI-K01-A01]    [LL1]       [01]
[GP6JLG2]     [RDJJH]   [HI-K01-A02]    [LL1]       [03]
[GP6JLG2]     [1H92N]   [HI-K01-A03]    [LL1]       [03]
[GP6JLG2]     [CMNM0]   [HI-K01-B01]    [LL1]       [05]
[GP6JLG2]     [VCYYW]   [HI-K01-B02]    [LL1]       [01]
[GP6JLG2]     [K3Y7X]   [HI-K01-B03]    [LL1]       [01]
[GP6JLG2]     [329N0]   [HI-K01-C01]    [LL1]       [11]
[GP6JLG2]     [R37F7]   [HI-K01-C02]    [LL1]       [02]
[GP6JLG2]     [3659V]   [HI-K01-C03]    [LL1]       [09]
```

In my Arduino I'll need a string concatenated like this: `HIK01C01LL101`.

Maybe I'll need to use a for in Arduino code to turn on all LEDs that I want because I'll have more than one `[Location]` for my `[TrackCode]`.

Is this right?

My Asp.NET code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Search.aspx.cs" Inherits="Search.Search" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            color: #3366FF;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="text-align: center">

        <h1><span class="auto-style1"><strong>LED TEST</strong></span></h1>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" style="height: 22px; width: 128px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" style="text-align: center; height: 26px; width: 56px" Text="Read" />

        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ItemPosition" Height="133px" Width="198px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TrackCode" HeaderText="TrackCode" SortExpression="TrackCode" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Pn" HeaderText="Pn" SortExpression="Pn" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Location" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Line" HeaderText="Line" SortExpression="Line" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ItemPosition" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TravelerConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [TrackCode], [Pn], [Location], [Line] FROM [ItemPosition] WHERE ([TrackCode] = @TrackCode)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:FormParameter FormField="TextBox1" Name="TrackCode" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace Search
{
    public partial class Search : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SerialPort ardo;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ardo = new SerialPort();
            ardo.PortName = "COM3";
            ardo.BaudRate = 9600;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ardo.Open();
            ardo.Write(TextBox1.Text);
            ardo.Close();

            //At here I need to use the information from "TextBox1.Text" (always a TrackCode), access my database and return only the columns containing some datas.
           //In this case, I just need the following columns: [Line], [Location], [Qtd] (Obviously, concatenated how I showed in Note1 above).
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the query you need

```
select replace(Location, '-', '') + Line + Qtd  from table
```

I hope this will help

UPDATE --

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Your connection string"))
{
    string query = "select replace(Location, '-', '') + Line + Qtd  from table";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
            .....
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, where do I use this select? I'm new using asp.net/c#

Comment: Thanks Jorge, I'll try to do this